# How to post the Theta 360 degree photo to facebook in ios

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, 360-degrees

I am using the Theta Camera SDK to take the picture in 360 degrees.

I want to post this photo to Facebook this is 360 photo.

```
         UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"IMG_0133.JPG"];


         NSString *token = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken].tokenString];
         NSDictionary *param = @{@"message": @"test",
                                 @"access_token": token,
                                  @"photo":image,
                                 @"allow_spherical_photo": [NSNumber numberWithBool:true]

                                 };

         FBSDKGraphRequest *request = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc]
                                       initWithGraphPath:@"me/photos"
                                       parameters:param
                                       HTTPMethod:@"post"];

         [request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection,
                                               id result,
                                               NSError *error)
          {

              if (!error)
              {
                  NSLog(@"post success");

              }
          }];
```

but it was post like normal image not with 360 view

Answer (score 0):

```
     UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc]initWithData:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey :@"image_NSdata]];
         NSData *imgData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1);
         NSLog(@"Size of Image(bytes):%ld",(unsigned long)[imgData length]);

         float actualHeight = image.size.height;
         float actualWidth = image.size.width;



         NSDictionary * postDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"equirectangular", [NSNumber numberWithFloat:actualWidth] ,[NSNumber numberWithFloat:actualHeight], [NSNumber numberWithFloat:actualWidth] ,[NSNumber numberWithFloat:actualHeight], @"0",@"0", nil]
             forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"ProjectionType", @"CroppedAreaImageWidthPixels",@"CroppedAreaImageHeightPixels", @"FullPanoWidthPixels",@"FullPanoHeightPixels", @"CroppedAreaLeftPixels",@"CroppedAreaTopPixels", nil]];


         NSError * error = nil;

         NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:postDictionary options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];
         NSString *resultAsString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
         NSLog(@"jsonData as string:\n%@ Error:%@", resultAsString,error);


         NSString *token = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken].tokenString];
         NSDictionary *param = @
                                 {

                                 @"access_token": token,
                                 @"photo":image,
                                 @"allow_spherical_photo": [NSNumber numberWithBool:true],
                                 @"spherical_metadata":resultAsString

                                 };

         FBSDKGraphRequest *request = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc]
                                       initWithGraphPath:@"me/photos"
                                       parameters:param
                                       HTTPMethod:@"post"];

         [request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection,
                                               id result,
                                               NSError *error)
          {

              if (!error)
              {
                  NSLog(@"post success");

              }
          }];
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a framework for this exact purpose:

https://github.com/AppCoders-io/Facebook360

Assuming that you've requested the permission to share, this is what you'd use:

```
[[Facebook360Manager sharedInstance] shareImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"spherical360.jpg"]
                                      userCaption:@"Example caption..."
                                    horizontalFOV:360.0
                                  sharePreference:FacebookShareManagerPreferenceSphericalImage
                                  completionBlock:^(NSError * _Nullable error, NSString * _Nullable postID) {
                                    if (error) {
                                      NSLog(@"Error: %@",error);
                                    }else{
                                      NSLog(@"Shared successfully. Post ID: %@",postID);
                                    }
                                  }];
```